# CSHTML file not opening in VS2013

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor, visual-studio-2013

I got a controller called " HomeController ", and when i right-click the Index function to generate a view for it, it crashes when generating an .cshtml file.

[image]

Visual Studio 2013 is unable to open ".cshtml" file it says the following:

[image]

**I've tried the following things:**

- Opened visual studio in administrator mode and remade the whole
  project
- Changed config file key versions
- Changed the config file webpage:Version value.

**Using:**

- MVC 4
- Visual Studio 2013 Proffesional

I hope you guys can make more sense of this than me.

Comment: Have you installed any updates / service packs for VS?

Comment: Does it actually create the file under the Views/Home folder? If not it sounds like the file creation is failing, but internally it still tries to do the next step which is open the file that was just created.

Comment: Yes the file has been created, everytime when attempting to open that file, the same error appears

Comment: Edit the project file by hand, and make sure the path to that file in the project (relative to the project's containing directory) is correct, and that the file exists and is readable.

Comment: Done all of that, file exists is readable and changes i make when i edit it in notepad are accepted when deploying. I just cannot open the file on whatever way possible in VS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might [have to:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23649710/visual-studio-2013-update-2-doesnt-open-cshtml)

> complete unistall and reinstall solved the problem for me.

Comment: As said in the main post, i already attempted changing the wepage:version keys. That did not solve the problem. In that case i might have to reinstall.

Comment: It would be informative to know what the exception being logged and stack trace was... if any. (I just had a nuget package removal bump down webpages:Version and couldn't find that in the troubleshooting list).